# Loading .npz file onto R

Tags: python, r, file-read

I am currently having a `d.npz` file that was born from Python that I would like to load it into R. I tried using the package `RcppCNPy`, but when I run `load("d.npz")`, it gave me this error message:

```
bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
```

I tried other tools like `source("d.npz")` or `readRDS("d.npz")`, but none worked out. Could anyone please help me solve this seemingly simple problem??

Comment: `RcppCNPy` does not support `.npz`, as stated in a few places. either you'd have to extend the code or maybe you can switch more easily from the `npz` file to compressed `npy` file(s)

Comment: I am finally able to read it, using simple thing like connection;p